# How to append in a loop for Excel file within pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, jupyter

I have two DataFrames.
The first one comes from an API, and the second one comes from an Excel file.

**df1**

| name | description | author | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a |  | Bob | inactive |
| b |  | Peter | active |
| c |  | Bob | inactive |
| d |  | Carl | active |
| e |  | Bob | inactive |
| f |  | Peter | active |

**df2**

| name | description |
| --- | --- |
| a | this is a description |
| b | this is another description |

I need to add the description from df2 to df1, according to each name on df1
How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.merge` to join two dataframes.

```
df1.merge(df2, on='name')
```

Comment: This results on clashing columns (description_x, description_y)

Comment: You can first drop the description column in df1 and then use df.merge. Then there will be no clash. You can also drop or renmae the column as well.